# How do I get the qualified name from a Type instance, in Dart?

Tags: dart, dart-mirrors

I have a instance of `Type`, but I want its fully qualified name. How can I do this? I know I have to use Mirrors (Dart's reflection library).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the new `reflectClass` top-level function from `dart:mirrors`.

Here's an example:

```dart
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:mirrors';

class Awesome {
  // ...
}

void main() {
  var awesome = new Awesome();
  Type type = awesome.runtimeType;
  ClassMirror mirror = reflectClass(type);
  Symbol symbol = mirror.qualifiedName;
  String qualifiedName = MirrorSystem.getName(symbol);

  query('#name').text = qualifiedName;
}
```

The `qualifiedName` should be something like:

```
http://127.0.0.1:3030/Users/sethladd/dart/type_name/web/type_name.dart.Awesome
```

Note, this works in build 21753 or higher. Also, this doesn't *currently* work in dart2js yet. We plan to support it in dart2js.

Comment: Great and with extension methods it would be even better, i.e. you could have: `String qualifiedName = reflectClass(type).qualifiedName.getName()` - [let Gilad know!](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=13) :)

Comment: What's the status of using a type directly like `reflectClass(Awesome)`?

Comment: @KaiSellgren: The implementation of reflectClass does not care whether you have gotten the Type object through obj.runtimeType or by using the type literal. Put differently, the status of reflectClass(Awesome) should be the same as the status of reflectClass((new Awesome()).runtimeType). If you experience this not being the case, please file a bug at http://dartbug.com .