# What should be the output of the code below? Is this correct?

Tags: dart, dart-mirrors

If I'm not wrong, this code should print:

```
 "dart.core.dynamic"
```

but following is printed:

```
 "dynamic"
```

My code:

```dart
    import 'dart:mirrors';

    main() {
      var mirror = reflectType(dynamic);
      var symbol = mirror.qualifiedName;
      print(symbol); // -> "dynamic"
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think "dynamic" is a perfectly good result.

The usual qualified name prefixes the type name with the declaring library's name. 
You are expecting it to prefix "dart.core", which is the name of the "dart:core" library, but "dynamic" is not declared in that library (https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_core.html), so that would be the wrong prefix to use.

The "dynamic" type is a synthetic type that is not declared in any library - there is no "class" or "typedef" declaration that could declare a type behaving as "dynamic" does. It's only specified by the specification and implemented internally in the compilers and runtime systems.

Having a qualified name with no prefix makes perfect sense in this case. It's the same you get for "void".

Answer (score 0):

here is the answer [How do I get the qualified name from a Type instance, in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16109993/how-do-i-get-the-qualified-name-from-a-type-instance-in-dart)

you have forgotten about

```
 Symbol symbol = mirror.qualifiedName;
 String qualifiedName = MirrorSystem.getName(symbol);
```

Comment: my question is not about getting the qualified name but if the qualified name returned is correct. Even if I use `MirrorSystem.getName (symbol)` the output is `"dynamic"` not `"dart.code.dynamic"`