# How to determine if two instances have the same type, in Dart?

Tags: class, dart, comparison, instance

Let's say I get two instances in my code and I don't know their types. How to check it?

If in Java, I can use this code:

```
a.getClass() == b.getClass()
```

But in Dart, I can't find similar methods. Although there is the `dart:mirrors` providing `reflect(instance)` function, which may let me do it, but I'm not sure if that's a correct solution since it looks complicated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```dart
a.runtimeType == b.runtimeType
```

Comment: Note that this might have false positives, because classes are allowed to override runtimeType. And in really contrived cases even a false negative. But for normal uses it should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think dart:mirrors (reflection) API helps you. Look at this page :

http://blog.dartwatch.com/2012/06/dartmirrors-reflection-api-is-on-way.html

Also you can look this question(with runtime solution)

[How do I get the qualified name from a Type instance, in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16109993/how-do-i-get-the-qualified-name-from-a-type-instance-in-dart)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to compare a and b you can use

```
if(a.runtimeType == b.runtimeType);
```

but if you want to confirm that a is the type you want you need to do this

```
if(a.runtimeType.toString()=="DivElement");//a is a div for instance
```

because runtimeType's value is not a string